# NanoSat/Small Satellite World Record

Tags: record, operations, nanosatellite

I have been trying to understand, small sat within 10-30 kg satellite what has been the longest operating satellite? Generally life of such missions is 6 months. Other heavy duty class satellite have, mission durations of ~15 years or so. Has any small satellite been able to get close to such number?

Even the NASA build [MarCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Cube_One) worked for ~9 Months, though considering that is deep space comparison may not be fair.

Comment: I edited to provide a range of mass. I mean I am looking qualitatively. Just curious how reliable can cots design be !

Comment: I think this is a great question! Just for fun: [How much did each MarCO 6U cubesat weigh?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45683/12102) and [Have there been any square 4U (2x2) cubesats?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45685/12102)