# How much did each MarCO 6U cubesat weigh?

Tags: design, deep-space, mass, marco-cubesats

Yes the answer is zero now because they are *weightless*, but I used past tense. In any event, let's try to find a good, reliable source for each spacecraft's mass and whether that number is dry or fully-fueled.

The interesting question [NanoSat/Small Satellite World Record](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45682/12102) got me thinking about the MarCOs. eoPortal's [MarCO (Mars Cube One)](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/content/-/article/marco) includes the graphic below, likely from some NASA presentation. It includes the following:

MarCO Overview:

- Volume: 2 x 6U (12 x 24 x 36 cm)
- Mass: 14.0 kg
- Power Generation:
- Earth: 35 W
- Data Rates: 62-8,000 bps
- Delta-V: > 40 m/s

The first line gives the volume for TWO MarCO satellites (2 x 6U) so I can't figure out for sure if the 14 kg applies to the pair or to each. I'm guessing that the next line's 35 W applies to only one, so maybe each was 14 kg.

That would make the cubesat's density about 0.75 g/cm^3 which seems awfully low already considering I've speculated at something like 1.6 kg/U in [Cubesat mass density (kg/U) statistics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32289/12102)

It's also not clear if that's dry weight or with its <s>fire extinguishers</s> thrusters fully loaded.

**Question:** Is there any independently reported mass for one MarCO satellite? If so, is it for dry or fully-fueled and loaded conditions?

---

> Figure 4: MarCO flight system overview (image credit: NASA/JPL)

[image: Figure 4: MarCO flight system overview (image credit: NASA/JPL)]